# How are #{...} construct used in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I dont understand how #{...} construct is used in Ruby.

I've seen in used in the regexp example on http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html

```
place = "tokyo"
/#{place}/.match("Go to tokyo")
    #=> #<MatchData "tokyo">
```

What exactly is this #{...} feature called and does anyone know of some good working examples of this.

Really appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: This is for inline Ruby code inside double quotes or slashes. `"#{1 + 1}"` => `"2"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is called *interpolation*, and allows you to convert placeholders to the value they represent...

http://kconrails.com/2010/12/08/ruby-string-interpolation/

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example that's a bit simpler:

```
place = "Tokyo"
puts "Go to #{place}"
```

What the `#{...}` construct does is to execute the ruby code that it contains, and return a string representation of the result, which then is embedded in the string where the construct appears.

Another example:

```
place = "Tokyo"
puts "#{place} is a #{place.class} of #{place.length} characters"
```

In other words, your example is equivalent to:

```
/tokyo/.match("Go to tokyo")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `#{...}` is especially useful and used quite a lot in metaprogramming. It helps you to dispatch methods dynamically without knowing the name of these methods before run time.

```
if conf.rc and File.exists?( conf.rc )
  YAML.load_file(conf.rc).each do |k,v|
    conf.send("#{k}=" , v)
  end
end
```

As you can see, until run time we do not know which methods are going to be dispatched. Through `.send` and `#{...}`, we can dynamically dispatch methods. For example, in above code depending on the values in `conf.rc` different methods can be dispatched.

Example is taken from [Metaprogramming Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476).